# Windows Batch loop all variables with findstr

Tags: variables, batch-file, findstr

In my Windows batch file I have a various amount of variables. Lets say I have the following variables:

```
set varTest1=test1
set varTest2=test2
set otherVar=variable500
set varS=string
set yetAnotherVar=foo
```

They do really make no sense buts thats not the point. I am looking for a method that prints out all values of variables that start with `var`:
So when I run my batch with a certain help parameter it should print out all three variables starting with `var` and its value.
The output could look like this:

```
These are the available variables:
varTest1 : test1
varTest2 : test2
varS : string
```

I created the following for reading the parameter:

```
IF "%1" == "" ( 
echo No help parameter was set. Program will exit. ) ELSE ( 
IF "%1" == "help" ( 
call :showAllAvailableVars ) ELSE (
echo Do something else))
```

Now I would have my method

```
:showAllAvailableVars
```

I think the solution could be something with the `findstr` method but I could not figure it out how to do that because `findstr` is mainly for files and not for searching through own program variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create array instead of different variables. Like,

```
set var[0]=test1

set var[1]=test2

set var[2]=string
```

then in your 'showAllAvailableVars' function do this

`for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !var[%%i]!`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `set var` to print all variables which begins with `var`.
See also `set /?`

Comment: or just do `set` all by it'self and see ALL the environmental variables. You could even tack on `find` to remove certain variables like this: `set | find /v "Path=" | find /v "ComSpec="`